# Ordering Selected keys according to the order of the given array

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code in a function.
My question is, how do I keep the order of my array intact "(8,7,6)" when I get the result?

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.id FROM table1
            join table2
            on table1.id = table2.number
            WHERE table2.id IN (8,7,6)
            GROUP BY table1.id
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table1.id)";

            $result = $this->conn->query( $sql );

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            $returnArray[] = $row; 

            return $returnArray;
```

In other words, how do I get my returnArray re ordered according to what the equivalent of my initial array indexes was in table1.

```
let say if 
8 = table1.id 4 
7 = table1.id 2
6 = table1.id 1
```

at the moment I get (1,2,4)
I like to get (4,2,1)

Comment: The query does not make sense, is it suppose to be "WHERE table2.number IN (8, 7, 6)" ?  And you say you would like to get 4,7,6 but dont you mean 8,7,6 ? If not try to explain it clearer.

Comment: Are the IN values always the same or can they be totally random, always 3 values? One way would be to use CASE WHEN in the select and give sort values that you can sort on. Like:   CASE WHEN 4 THEN 1 WHEN 7 THEN 2 WHEN 6 THEN 3 ELSE 99 END. Just an example until we have more info...

Comment: @FSDaniel thanks, You were right, I edited the query and fixed it. The array  I have put here comes from an implode variable and sorted in another query, the values and their number could vary.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the IN array will be sorted. If it is always sorted, like the example above, this will work:

```
    SELECT table1.id FROM table1
    join table2
    on table1.id = table2.number
    WHERE table2.id IN (8,7,6)
    GROUP BY table1.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table1.id)
    ORDER BY table2.id DESC
```

If the values can be in a non sorted order then you need to give values to a column that you can sort by.

A hardcoded example would be:

```
    SELECT table1.id, 
            CASE WHEN table2.id = 8 THEN 1
            WHEN table2.id = 7 THEN 2
            WHEN table2.id = 6 THEN 3
            ELSE 99 END as ordering
    FROM table1
    join table2
    on table1.id = table2.number
    WHERE table2.id IN (7,6,8)
    GROUP BY table1.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table1.id)
    ORDER BY ordering
```

If neither work you need a temp table where you insert the values and another value with the sort order and then you join that table and sort by the sort value.

If this dont work then add more info about your needs.

Comment: Thanks, my array is always sorted but `ORDER BY table2.id DESC` didn't work. it has to be something like ` ORDER BY table2.id $myArray` instead of DESC.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, i see that i wrote in down incorrectly, i will modify the last example.